# Is method parameter forwarding possible in Scala?

Tags: scala, methods, parameter-passing

Is it possible to write something similar to:

```
def foo(x: Int, y: Double)

def bar(x: Int, y: Double) = foo(_)
```

I would like to avoid repeating myself in saying:

```
def foo(x: Int, y: Double)

def bar(x: Int, y: Double) = foo(x, y)
```

So in the case where the both parameter lists are the same in type and size and no repositioning of parameters should happen, can something like parameter forwarding achieved?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Yes, if the function bar is doing nothing other than forwarding exactly on to `foo`, you can do the following:

```
def foo(x : Int, y : Double) { println("X: " x + " y: " + y) }
def bar = foo _

bar(1,3.0)
//prints out "X: 1 y: 3.0"
```

In this case the underscore indicates that you want to return the function `foo` itself, rather than calling it and returning the reuslt. This means that when `bar` is called, it will simply return the function `foo`, which will then be called with the arguments you provided.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, but it's a bit of a pun

```
def foo(x: Int, y: Double):Int = 3

def bar = foo(_, _)
```

In this case bar is not a method taking an int and a double.  Instead it's a method taking no arguments, returning a function that takes and int an a double.  From the caller's point of view, these can be used interchangeably.

```
bar(3, 5.9)  // expands to bar apply(3, 5.9), which calls foo
```